# Is it possible to bypass HHVM?

Tags: ubuntu, hhvm

I've been hunting on the Internet and not cannot find a way to do this (if its even possible) - to bypass HHVM in an individual script or bypass the alternative link to hhvm.

We run heaps of command line PHP scripts on our server, and HHVM has been a god send in terms of speeding those up, and also reducing load.  The problem is one particular script, magmi (Magento import command line tool) is not working as expected -> HHVM is so fast it skips ahead on inserts and wants to insert a configurable product ahead of the related simple (simples must be inserted before configurable products).

SO .. Because we use PHP so much, our default behaviour (and web service) is set to default all php requests to hhvm.

```
/usr/bin/update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/php php /usr/bin/hhvm 60
```

The obvious workaround is to create a shell script to, delete that alternative, run the magmi script, then reinstall that alternative.  BUT .. this is not ideal as other scripts on the server run quite frequently (cron.php for Magento every 5 minutes+others).

What I want to know is there are way to bypass the alternative (as calling /usr/bin/php directly defaults to hhvm)?

OR is it possible to bypass HHVM on the command line?

Using Ubuntu Trusty, latest version of HHVM.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/usr/bin/php5`, which is the default location of the `php-cli` binary.